# Yamaha NMAX Won't Start

Tags: starter, yamaha

It has strong battery still. The horn is loud and I have all the lights. It would just click but there's no juice nor rev. What could be wrong?

Comment: solenoid failed, starter failed or bad battery.

Comment: loose or corroded connection?

Comment: Thanks! You're right. The connection has some corrosion. I didn't know it was that simple.

Comment: spray contacts with contact cleaner. The solenoid/actuator corrosion possibly.